# The role of square brackets [] after calling different function

Tags: python

Why do we use square brackets after a function? What does it do?
For example:

```
start_id= np.argwhere(names[Var1, :] != 0).ravel()[ :Var2]
```

Comment: It indexes into whatever the function returns, same as if you did `temp = np.argwhere(names[Var1, :] != 0).ravel()` then `start_id = temp[ :Var2]`.

Comment: Agnostic of numpy, `def a(): return [42]` then call it with `a()[0]` and see what happens.